# Elastic Nest Adding Meta to Aggregations

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am successfully creating Aggregations with my Elastic NEST query but I would like to pass some additional information in I have seen that I can use Meta for this, but I cannot find any documentation for doing it in NEST.

HERE is my nest Aggregations code

```
.Aggregations(aa => aa.Terms("groups", sp => sp.Field(p => p.ProductSpecification.Suffix("name"))
                    .Aggregations(aaa => aaa
                        .Terms("attribute", tt => tt.Field(ff => ff.ProductSpecification.Suffix("value"))))
```

Basically id like to be add say SpecificationId to the meta any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `meta` per aggregation, and it'll be returned on the aggregation response

```
var response = client.Search<User>(s => s
    .Size(0)
    .Query(q => +q
        .Term(m => m
            .Field(f => f.Badges.First().Name)
            .Value("c#")
        )
    )
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .SignificantTerms("badges", st => st
            .Field(f => f.Badges.First().Name)
            .Meta(m => m
                .Add("meta_1", "value_1")
                .Add("meta_2", 2)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, was going down these lines if i want the meta value to be pulled from elastic data what would I do I have tried the following with no joy 
.Aggregations(aa => aa.Terms("groups", sp => sp.Field(p => p.ProductSpecification.Suffix("name")).Meta(m => m.Add("specificationId",sp.Field(p=>p.ProductSpecification.Suffix("specificationId"))) )

Comment: `meta` can't do that. It's essentially a way to be able to send additional values with an aggregation in a request, and for those values to be returned in a response. For example, it might be used to identify the aggregation in some way. If you need to have matching documents for an aggregation returned, take a look at `top_hits` aggregation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

Comment: So I cant bind any additional dynamic data then, that is a shame.In my setup I am getting aggregations to bring back the grouped filters for my search but for each "group" there is also some description data in the index that I would like to pull back, i guess I will have to do a separate call to the db or index to fetch that data.

Comment: @rs82uk separate calls or inner hits are the way to go